# can a result of $conn->query(...) be not null with 0 records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I came across the following in some old PHP code that I have to work on.  My question is, are both those Ifs required?  In other words, if a result is returned it must have returned greater than zero records, right? And the converse - meaning if $result is False, can I assume that no records have been found?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE ownerphone=$pn";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result) {
    $count = $result->num_rows;
    if ($count > 0){
       ....Stuff happens here...
    } else {
        ...What happens here?...
    }
} else {
     ...Other Stuff happens here
}
```

Comment: if result is false it means that your query fails to execute

Comment: `$result` is `NULL` when the query failed to complete either because it is invalid or for other reasons (server disconnected, server disk full etc).

Comment: So $result is TRUE even with 0 records returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are required.

> if a result is returned it must have returned greater than zero records, right?

Wrong.

If you don't get a result then you got an *error* and you won't have an object to read the number of results back from.

You *can* get zero rows back from a successful request.

> if $result is False, can I assume that no records have been found?

Well, yes. Sort of. That's why the `if` statement stops you checking to see if there are a number of rows if the result is False.

… but not getting rows back because there was an error is different to not getting rows back because there were none to find.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't assume this. `$conn->query()` returns `false` if there's an error trying to perform a query. A `SELECT` query that doesn't match any rows is not an error.

Errors include incorrect syntax in the query or problems communicating with the database server.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php);

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

This means that it will bascically never return `null`. The first check (`if ( $result )` is just to make sure all went well, and you got some kind of a response from the database. The second one is to count your rows; getting a result doesn't imply your query actually returns data, because maybe you're searching for stuff that is just not there.

Comment: So what is the purpose then of $result? I should checkmysqli_error($conn) instead (only).